# How to get QTableWidget columns label value

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to get QTableWidget's column label value? The inverse of setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString) in Qt and the equivalent of GetColLabelValue (int col) wxWidgets: I'm looking for a long time in the Qt documentation but could not find the command I need

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your QTableWidget is named table, and you want from column index columnID:

```
QString str = table.horizontalHeaderItem(columnID)->text();
```